# api's toi connect to printer

Tags: android

How to connect an android device to a wireless printer through native app.I mean with are there any apis trough which we can connect an android phone to a printer.can anyone help.thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure.. have think  of wireless ad-hoc connection

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/140-api-for-printing-from-android-applications .

This is the useful link i found while i was searching.But i think the .apk that they have provided has expired so we need to install new version from android market.

Comment: Cant imagine you confused canvas printing with actual bluetooth printer. The link you are showing will print an image on your mobile screen. No bluetooth involved and no connection.

Comment: i didn't test it but there is a utility "send to print.apk" along with the code so might be is is able to connect to printers.

Comment: so read it again, that utility method you are talking about just shows google logo on your screen. No printing going on.

Comment: Hey u r wrong.. READ THIS-->Android developers, you can now enable printing to network printers within your own applications using the "Send 2 Printer" application's build-in API. http://hit-mob.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=66

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem there are api's to connect to bluetooth device but printing data and all that stuff comes with printer sdk.

Download some of CITIZEN printer sdk's, they are free and comes with samples you can just use as it is. an example you can use., https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=WH62&actp=RSS